# Debian installation - how to correctly partition the disk?

Tags: debian, installation, debian-bullseye, partition-alignment

My system:

- most recent Debian 11 image
- vServer running at my hosting provider
- virtualized via Xen
- normal HDD, no SSD; no lvm or raid used

Somehow I managed to install Debian 11 with misaligned partitions.  (this question is a follow-up of [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1118519/possible-to-correct-the-alignment-of-partition-without-data-loss))
fdisk says:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1               2 2095151103 2095149056  999G 83 Linux
/dev/xvda2      2095153150 2097149951    1996802  975M  5 Extended
/dev/xvda5      2095153152 2097149951    1996800  975M 82 Linux swap
```

The weird thing: I recently installed another Debian on a vServer having the same setup in almost the same way, and on that machine all is ok (first sector starts at 2048)

What I did:

- expert installation
- on the machine where all is ok: chose 'guided, use whole disk'; I did not enter the menu for manual or guided partitioning
- on the faulty machine: I thought about manual partitioning, entered the menu, but then aborted without writing anything to disk and let the debian installer make partitioning

Result is different as you can see in above output
(my biggest problem right now is that grub has not enough space to be installed)

How is this possible???
When I manually partition the disk when installing debian, how can I be sure that partitions are aligned??
Any thoughts what could have gone wrong here?

Update:
reinstalled the vServer, manually partitioned the whole disk; then, even before finishing installation checked with fdisk in another terminal window: everything ok this time, first partition start at sector 2048

Question stays: how can it be possible that the debian installer screws up the partitioning sometimes?